# Stuck in emergency mode with ACPI errors

Tags: boot, acpi, fsck

Since yesterday when I try to boot Ubuntu on my Thinkpad I just reach the emergency mode, without being able to resume to a normal booting. This occurred right after my laptop suddenly died from an empty battery.

At first there was an error saying `/dev/sda5/ contains a file system with errors, check forced`, so I tried running `fsck -y /dev/sda5` after unmounting it. This seemed to go without error, and after that this error disappeared, but I am still stuck in emergency mode. The error messages that are left are now linked to ACPI (`ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer]`)

I am putting here pictures of the errors before and after running fsck:

before fsck
[image: before fsck]

after fsck
[image: after fsck]

Rebooting just leads back to the emergency mode. I'm relatively new to Ubuntu and I don't know what to try anymore. Any help would be very appreciated!